# Rendering CDATA with Haskell XHT Library

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

How can I make [HXT](https://wiki.haskell.org/HXT) library to output CDATA?

For example running `test` in this snippet will result in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<texts>hello&lt;br>world!</texts>
```

---

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

hello :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
hello =
  mkelem "texts" [] [txt "hello<br>world!"]

test = runX $
  root [] [hello]
  >>>
  writeDocument [withIndent yes] "somefile.xml"
```

But I need it to render:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<texts><![CDATA[hello<br>world!]]></texts>
```

Can `HXT` automatically detect if CDATA is necessary?

Comment: Is explicitly calling `mkCdata` inconvenient in you program? I didn't find such an option while grepping over the source of hxt.

Comment: I can call `mkCdata` myself in the program. But how? This is a type error: `X.mkelem "texts" [] [X.mkCdata "hello<br>world!"]`

Comment: `mkCdata` is an arrow, you have to combine it with another constant `String` arrow like `constA "hello<br>world!" >>> mkCdata`

Comment: Thanks. What's the type of this function? `cDataTxt txt = mkCdata <<< constA txt` ? I tried `cDataTxt :: String -> a n XmlTree` and some other variants but none of them worked. How can I write it in point-free style?

Comment: It's of the same type with `txt` which is `ArrowXml a => String -> a n XmlTree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find such an option while grepping over the source of hxt, but you always can call `mkCdata` explicitly to construct a CDATA text node:

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

hello :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
hello =
  mkelem "texts" [] [constA "hello<br>world!" >>> mkCdata]
```

And you may define a function simliar to `txt`, in the same manner how `txt` is defined [in the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/src/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#txt):

```
import qualified Text.XML.HXT.DOM.XmlNode as XN

txtCdata :: ArrowXml a => String -> a n XmlTree
-- XN.mkCdata :: XmlNode n => String -> n, XmlTree is an instance of XmlNode
-- constA :: Arrow a => c -> a b c, b is free
txtCdata = constA . XN.mkCdata

hello :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree XmlTree
hello =
  mkelem "texts" [] [txtCdata "hello<br>world!"]
```